# How to skip blank line while taking input from user in python?

Tags: python, user-input

I want to skip blank line (no value entered by user). I get this error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "candy3.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "candy3.py", line 5, in main
    num=input()
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

My code is:

```
def main():
    tc=input()
    d=0
    while(tc!=0):
        num=input()
        i=0
        count=0
        for i in range (0, num):
            a=input()
            count=count+a
        if (count%num==0):
            print 'YES'
        else:
            print 'NO'
        tc=tc-1     
main()
```

Comment: which version of python are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Use raw_input, and convert manually. This is also more save. For a full explaination, see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output#input.28.29).
For example, you could use the code below to skip anything which is not an integer.

```
x = None
while not x:
try:
    x = int(raw_input())
except ValueError:
    print 'Invalid Number'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're getting is expected, read the [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) docs.

> input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised

Try something like this and the code will be capturing the possible exceptions produced by input function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tc = input("How many numbers you want:")
    d = 0
    while(tc != 0):
        try:
            num = input("Insert number:")
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error (try again),", str(e)
            continue

        i = 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, num):
            try:
                a = input("Insert number to add to your count:")
                count = count + a
            except Exception, e:
                print "Error (count won't be increased),", str(e)

        if (count % num == 0):
            print 'YES'
        else:
            print 'NO'
        tc = tc - 1
```